How to change auth persistence time in line liff
everyone.
I'm working on an asp.net core project integrated with Line LIFF(Line Front-end Framework).
And I want to change the authentication persistence time longer.
But I can't find the right solution for it.
<script src="https://static.line-scdn.net/liff/edge/2/sdk.js"></script>
<script type="module">
        liff.init({liffId: "My Liffid"});
</script>

If we use the above code, it redirects to Line login page and it returns to the origin page after login.
I want to change the Line authentication persistence time.
I found this value is stored in expires_in variable of the response json data.
But I want to set it before login so that change the re-login requiring time.
Are there someone who is good at it?
I'm looking for your kind advice.
Thanks in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
